# Deadlock in Try-catch-finally

Tags: java, multithreading, deadlock

I am mobile right now so can't provide the code. 
I initiated 3 threads inside a try block.. (inside a try method coz I am using buffer-reader? I also used some  deprecated methods. That will ensure dead lock.
My question is why is the finally block not executed now ?

Comment: If it is deadlocked, how is it going to continue to the finally block?

Comment: Because the `finally` is invoked when `try` finished either normally or abruptly. If you put in a deadlock or infinite loop or whatever in the `try`, neither `finally` nor `catch` will ever be executed.

Comment: The code is still executing.. but it's a deadlock... waiting for resources... hence....

Comment: nice thinking (y). i want to see your code. post it here when you login.

Comment: Rather than asking at a time when you *can't* provide the code, why not wait until you can ask a better question? Basically, it's very hard to answer your question without seeing any code whatsoever...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The finally block will only be executed when the method  will  come out of the try block.

**TRY-->catch-->finally(always)** this is how the methods will be executed.

Mainly Try-Catch-Finally are used to catch exception. **dead-Lock is not an Exception**.
If there is any Exception (Io Exception as You are using buffered reader)Then only your finally and catch blocks will execute.(TRY block is deadlocked).

the finally block is guaranteed to run after the try block (stated by #Elliott).

Answer (score 1):

If you deadlock in a try block the finally block will not run, because the finally block is guaranteed to run after the try block (which doesn't end). As an analogy, if I offer to pay you $100 after you count to infinity from 1 I will never have to pay you (because you can't count to infinity in finite time). Make sure you acquire and release locks in the *same order* everywhere.

Comment: Oh I never read That try block needs to end. Sorry guys to bother..  What if I do the same thing in catch block or finally block ?

Comment: @Jump3r A deadlock is a deadlock. It will not end.

Answer (score 0):

The `finally` block will be executed if the `try` block finishes normally or an error occurs. If you have a deadlock in the `try` block, then it will not reach the `finally` block.